# Como executar uma função em ajax ao abrir a página?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Possuo a seguinte função em Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tra.php",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    suceess: function(Last)
    {
         line.originalData[0].push(Last);
         line.originalData[0].shift();

         RGraph.SVG.redraw();

    }
        });
    setTimeout(function () { update() }, 50);
}

 update();
```

Porém, a função update() não está iniciando, como faço para que a mesma funcione?

Comment: Função em Ajax assim que carregar? Normalmente é melhor já na primeira resposta do seu site fornecer essas informações. Uma chamada assíncrona a menos é um cliente feliz a mais e metade da carga no servidor para o seu modelo de busca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "tra.php",
data: {},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(Last)
{
     line.originalData[0].push(Last);
     line.originalData[0].shift();

     RGraph.SVG.redraw();
     setTimeout(function () { update() }, 50);
}
    });

}

update();
```

Answer (score 0):

O trecho de código abaixo está fora da função *success*, e a função *success* está escrita errada.

```
setTimeout(function () { update() }, 50);}
```